# how to strongly secure a wire over a couch frame to stretch seat spring webbing

Tags: woodworking, furniture, wooden-furniture

I have a wire piping that used to be secure around the frame perimeter of my couch base so that a flexolator webbing with springs would be stretched taut and clip onto it.  However, this piping has come loose and the wire that used to secure the piping frame has broke so now the webbing sags.  I'd like to clip/secure the piping so that it can be strong enough again to clip on the springs to it.  I tried heavy duty staples but that was too weak against the pull.  What is the best way to secure the piping back onto the frame to withstand the force of the springs and stretching when it clips back on.

Similar to this photo, the springs clip into a cable/wire/piping that goes around the frame.

[image]

Comment: We need to see YOUR couch construction in order to provide an informed answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would probably drill holes through the piping and screw/bolt it directly to the frame. They won't budge if fastened properly with screws. I guess I would glue it as well...

Or how about some straps like these on both sides of each pipe:

[image]

Comment: the one thing I'm afraid of is as you can see in the photo its sandwich plywood and I would have to drill on the edge side and not the flat - so maybe it would split the wood?

Comment: also how would I protect the piping from chafing wearing out on the screw thread, should I use something else to protect against the rubbing?